# How to higlight a TD when link is clicked

Tags: jquery, css

How can I make a `<td>` cell selected with a color when I click a link after load?

```
<td class="allCommsCSS">
    <a id="removevisited" href="todays.aspx?s=c">Today</a>
</td>
```

any idea?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {
    $("a").on('click',function () {$(this).parents('td:first').css('background-color','red'})
});
```

I used parents, for if one day you wrap the `a` with Div  - it will highlight the TD.

Answer (score 0):

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sA5C7/4/)

jQuery

```
$("td a").on('click',function () {
    $(this).parents('td').addClass('bgColor');
})
```

CSS

```
.bgColor { 
   background-color:yellow;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you want to remove previous selection when new **`<td>`** is clicked:

**JS:**

```
$('td').click( function() {

    $(this).parents('table').find('td').each( function( index, element ) {
        $(element).removeClass('selected');
    });

    $(this).addClass('selected');       
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.selected{ background-color:green; color:#ffffff; }
```

## Demo

Answer (score 0):

$("#removevisited").click(function () {
        $(".allCommsCSS").css("background-color", "yellow");
        });

Comment: Thanks Amit.But this only selects the first one.I have multiple rows and cells.How can it iterate through eaach one.
Thanks